# "Unable to determine stack" exception - ExactTarget down?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Using ExactTarget's official PHP Fuel SDK, I am daily getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to determine stack 
using /platform/v1/endpoints/: Unable to determine stack using /platform/v1/endpoints/:' 
in /path/to/vendor/exacttarget/fuel-sdk-php/ET_Client.php:67

Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/mylib.php(61): ET_Client->__construct(true, true, Array)
#1 /path/to/myscript.php(7): include_once('/path/to...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /path/to/vendor/exacttarget/fuel-sdk-php/ET_Client.php on line 67
```

Yesterday it included more information:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to determine stack using 
/platform/v1/endpoints/: Unable to determine stack using /platform/v1/endpoints/:{"documentation":
"https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/500","errorcode":0,"message":"Internal Server Error"}' in
/home/iaprod/public_html/core/components/salesforce/vendor/exacttarget/fuel-sdk-php/ET_Client.php:67
Stack trace:
#0 /home/iaprod/public_html/core/components/salesforce/cmd/lib/init.php(61): ET_Client->__construct(true, true, Array)
#1 /home/iaprod/public_html/core/components/salesforce/cmd/runDaily.php(9): include_once('/home/iaprod/pu...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/iaprod/public_html/core/components/salesforce/vendor/exacttarget/fuel-sdk-php/ET_Client.php on line 67
```

The documentation link given is broken, but it implies the issue is at the ExactTarget's end.

Can anyone confirm this is the problem?

Comment: It was down for a little while earlier today... its back up now though. Are you still getting this error?

Comment: Not continuously but it's back this morning, with a "Scheduled Maintenance" note attached.